# running vbscript with psexec?

Tags: vbscript, pstools

Is it possible to run a vbscript remotely with psexec? Normally the field of psexec calls for an exe file, so can this be changed or manipulated to deal with a vbs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by making cscript.exe the command to use and then the vbs file is its argument. Fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: Yep!  That's how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

This post suggests it is:

- http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic7879.html

Comment: I looked at that and still am a little confused. Will the csript exe be copied along with the vbscript to the remote machine?

Comment: cscript.exe is available in Windows by default: `c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe`. You should be able to run vbs like that: `cscript some.vbs` on any machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
Psexec \\\remoteServer cscript c:\scripts\file.vbs
```